# xamarin.forms call hung up event using android telephony

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app , I am accessing android telephony API.In my app, user can make call from a button click. I created a broadcast receiver and provided the PhoneStateListener inside the OnReceive. I called the broadcast receiver from my shared code at the time of calling. However the **CallState.Idle** will call at  the first time. I added a messeging center at the CallState.Idle. But the problem is it will call at the time of Broad cast receiver call. What I want is the CallState.Idle event at call hung up. How to achieve this?

**My Main Actvity with Broadcast Receiver.**

```
   [BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.companyname.SampleOutgoingcall.OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver")]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall, TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged })]

        public class OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public int READ_CALL_LOG { get; private set; }

            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                StateListener phoneStateListener = new StateListener();
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
                telephonyManager.Listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListenerFlags.CallState);
            }
        }



        public class StateListener : PhoneStateListener
        {
            public override void OnCallStateChanged(CallState state, string incomingNumber)
            {

                base.OnCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                switch (state)
                {
                    case CallState.Ringing:
                        break;
                    case CallState.Offhook:

                        try
                        {
                            MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "CallAndroidRinging");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                        break;
                    case CallState.Idle:
// Trying to get the call hung up event
                        try
                        {
                            MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "CallEndedAndroid");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
```

**My shared code which will call Broadcast Receiver on call.**

```
DependencyService.Get<OutgoingcallTrack>().Send(phonenumber.Text);
```

**My interface**

```
namespace SampleOutgoingcall
{
   public interface OutgoingcallTrack
    {
        void Send(string text);

    }
}
```

**My android class**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(OutgoingCall))]
namespace SampleOutgoingcall.Droid
{
    class OutgoingCall : OutgoingcallTrack
    {
        public void Send(string text)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.companyname.SampleOutgoingcall.OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver");        
            Forms.Context.SendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you would want to send the message only if the call was received, so I would suggest in **OFFHOOK** set a bool variable to true to know the call was received and later in if the variable is true then in **IDLE** send the message and set the variable false for next call. You don't mind if it was incoming call or outgoing call.

```
bool iscallreceived=false;
```

```
switch (state)
{
    case CallState.Ringing:
        break;


    case CallState.Offhook:

        try
        {
           MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "CallAndroidRinging");
           iscallreceived=true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        break;


    case CallState.Idle:
    // Trying to get the call hung up event
    if(iscallreceived)
    {
      try
      {
         MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "CallEndedAndroid");
         iscallreceived=false;
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      }
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: I only want the outgoing call event

Comment: In your case OnCallStateChanged will only been called when outgoing call. So you don't worry about this .